# Artisan queue processing process hanging

Tags: php, queue, cpanel, whm, laravel-7

I have recently updated my application from laravel version 5.1 to 7.0.4. I have a cron job that runs `php artisan queue:work --queue=emails --tries=3` that all of a sudden hangs and gets caught up in an infinite loop. The error that i get is:

```
stat("/project-directory/storage/framework/cache/ee/2f/ee2f842aa7bb1f53edf3a2ed2c09a1807ffa6c90", 0x7fff03e86950) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/project-directory/storage/framework/down", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x55b5d338abb0, ~[ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL SEGV CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU SYS RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7efe52ce73f0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ALRM], NULL, 8) = 0
```

I have checked the permissions on the data folder as well as the general storage folders and they are set correctly. I have also tried clearing the cache as well as clear/delete the config files manually and using artisan but the process still hangs.

I am hosting the application on Cpanel running Php 7.3. Other configs i have include `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync` , `CACHE_DRIVER=file` as well as

```
'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path'   => storage_path('framework/cache/data'),
        ],
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Unfortunately nothing is being written away to the logs

Comment: do you have OPCache enabled on the server? If so, try clearing that, doing composer dump-autoload and restarting queue service afterwards.

Comment: Hi @DanielProtopopov, i had OPCache disabled on the server...enabled it and ran composer dump-autoload without any success...

Comment: By putting the system into maintenance mode and running the command, the ee folder under storage/framework/data folder was created. When i made the application live again, the process was no longer hanging. I dont know how or why this worked...

Comment: That’s quite an upgrade up two major versions, so it’s surprising everything else works! ;)